# How to implement version control inside a web app?

Tags: php, laravel, git, version-control, dms

I'm building **DMS** (Document management system) using **PHP framework Laravel**.

One of the requirements is allowing users to version control files, close to what google docs does.

I've been searching for days without any clue, I don't want to re-impalement the wheel, there's a lot of really good VCS already including **git** which I'm thinking of utilizing it using php to implement the versioning features.

I just don't know how to start or even my way of thinking is valid!

Comment: If you want to use git, this might help: https://github.com/libgit2/php-git

Comment: Woah, pretty complicated stuff down there :(

Comment: Just check out their API page: http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#v0.20.0

Answer (score 0):

What you need is real-time system (achieved via socket programming) so that everyone is updated about the contents in realtime; also who is doing what: Like if there are two users A and B and they have opened the same file then A should know what the B is doing and vice versa; you would use client events for that. Have a look here:
https://laracasts.com/series/get-real-with-laravel-echo

Or

Look into Web RTC: https://webrtc.org/

GIT is a different thing given your requirements what I understood.

Comment: Collaboration is not the requirement/problem here, version control is.

Comment: What version file look like w.r.t two users, give a scenario here; two use A and B & one file file1.txt

Comment: Normal version control like what git does!